# Is $\displaystyle \lim_{\,x\to x_0}(f(x)-f(x_0))$ always equal to $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f:(a\,..b) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ or, for some $\xi \in (a\,..b),$ $f:(a\,..b)\setminus{\{{\xi}}\} \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Let $x_0 \in (a\,..b)$ or $x_0 \in (a\,..b)\setminus{\{\xi}\}$.

Let $\displaystyle \lim_{\,x\to x_0}(f(x)-f(x_0))$ exist.

Is it  possible to prove that for all such $f$, for all $x_0$,$\displaystyle \lim_{\,x\to x_0}(f(x)-f(x_0))=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if and only if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. For example, if 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if }x\neq 0\\0\text{ if }x=0\end{cases}$$
then
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-f(0))=1$$

Answer (score 2):

As soon as $f(x)$ is not continous in $x_0$, the limit does not have to be zero.

Example:

$f = 
\begin{cases}
|x|, ~\text{for}~|x|>0,\\
1,~\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

We do not have zero limit for $x_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! There are plenty of functions that can't full fill this requisite. All of them are discontinuous at a point within the bounded region. Let me give you an example:

Lets define 
$$f:= \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} 
f(x)=1 &\mathrm{if}& x\in \mathbb Q\\
f(x)=0 & & o.w.
\end{array} \right.$$

Now lets play the $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ game for say $x_0\in[0,1]$. This is where I pick an $\varepsilon$ and you try to find a $\delta$ that will meet the conditions. I will pick mine to be, $0<\varepsilon < 1$. Now can you find a $\delta$ that will meet those conditions?